# Array difference from two arrays and detect the changes

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I want to detect the old / new values in a new array.

Just for info, I am using PHP.

I would like to achieve it in a minimal coding without extra for loops.

**Old Array**

```
$oldArr = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 9
];
```

**New Array**

```
$newArr = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 6,
    3 => 7
];
```

$newArr should be as below.

**Desired output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [action] => not changed
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 5
            [action] => not changed
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 6
            [action] => added
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 7
            [action] => added
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [value] => 4
            [action] => removed
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [value] => 9
            [action] => removed
        )

)
```

**Tried code**

```
$removed         = array_diff_key($old, $new);
  $added           = array_diff_key($new, $old);
  $possiblyChanged = array_intersect_key($old, $new);
  foreach ($possiblyChanged as $key => $value)
  {
      if ($new[$key] !== $value)
      {
          $changed[$key] = $new[$key];
      }
  }
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve this then?

Comment: @Epodax: I am trying to achieve it with functions and without looping, but I am not getting any idea to do it in minimal coding, BTW, I've edited my answer as well.

Comment: `$result = array_merge(
    array_map(function($value) { return ['value' => $value, 'action' => 'unchanged']; }, $unchanged),
    array_map(function($value) { return ['value' => $value, 'action' => 'added']; }, $added),
    array_map(function($value) { return ['value' => $value, 'action' => 'removed']; }, $removed)
);
`

Comment: @Epodax: Did you see my updated question, what I tried and what and how I would like to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `array_combine` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$removed = [];
$keys = ['value', 'action'];

foreach ($newArr as $k => &$v) {        
    if ($newArr[$k] == $oldArr[$k]) {
        $v = array_combine($keys, [$v, 'not changed']);
    } else {
        $v = array_combine($keys, [$v, 'added']);
        $removed[] = array_combine($keys, [$oldArr[$k], 'removed']);
    }
}
$newArr = array_merge($newArr, $removed);

print_r($newArr);  // will show the needed output
```

[**DEMO** link](https://eval.in/631596)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$arrayDiff = array_merge($newArr,(array) $oldArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solved your problem:

```
$var = array_merge (array_diff($first_array, $second_array), array_diff($second_array, $first_array));
```

Comment: Please see the desired output.